# Is there any comparison of learning curvre of NHibernate vs. LINQ To Entities?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, orm, linq-to-entities

I am practicing NHibernate recently and it does not look that much easy. (This is my impression after reading [Manning NHibernate in Action](http://www.manning.com/kuate/) book which has tons of interesting details to pay attention for a better configuration and usage).

I was wondering if it is like this complicated(!) when it comes to LINQ to Entities.

Is there any comparison of learning curvre of NHibernate vs. LINQ To Entities ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bunch of questions regarding usability and other stuff. The all seem to agree a bit in the fact that the higher level of flexibility that NHibernate provides comes with the price of a bit bigger learning curve. In my personnal experience, it does seems that the majority of people seem to have an easier time learning and getting started with LINQ to Entities or any other Microsoft out of the box technology.
Take a look at some of these questions, they may help a bit:
[When choosing an ORM, is LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Entities better than NHibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71955/when-choosing-an-orm-is-linq-to-sql-or-linq-to-entities-better-than-nhibernate)

[linq to entities vs fluent nhibernate vs linq to sql (Help)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129393/linq-to-entities-vs-fluent-nhibernate-vs-linq-to-sql-help)

Also there are some [tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278046/free-nhibernate-helper-tools) that help with nhibernate. We still use mapping files and it's not that complicated writting them by hand though.